# Error : Requested role is not associated to cluster ,when trying to read redshift table from pyspark in emr

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

Trying to read redshift table from pyspark in emr, getting “requested role is not associated to cluster error”

Role is already attached to redshift
df.count() is working, df.show() throws above mentioned error